# SQL Query Case with Where/Having Clause

Tags: mysql, sql

How do you apply a Where or Having clause to a query? I am having problems with the Having clause.

```
DECLARE @dtDate DATE
SET @dtDate = GETDATE();

with EMS as
    (
       select * from ReportingView.WTA where FiscalMonth = DATENAME(MONTH, @dtDate) + ', ' +  DATENAME(YEAR, @dtDate) and ProductGroup = 'AAD'
    )

select 
       [ID]
      ,(CASE 
            WHEN Entitlements <= 0 THEN '0'
            ELSE CAST([Activations] as float) / [Entitlements]
        END) as Utilization 
from EMS
**HAVING  Utilization >= .25**
```

Comment: Is it like this

HAVING  COUNT(
  CASE 
   WHEN Entitlements <= 0 THEN '0'
            ELSE CAST([Field Activations Capped] as float) / [Entitlements]
        END
) > 0.25

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both a `where` and a `having` clause go at the end of your query. If you have both, then the `where` comes before the `having`.

In your case, your `having` is not working, because `having` is only to be used with `group by`. `having` is essentially a `where` clause for aggregate values (such as `sum`, `count`, etc)

---

**Examples:**

**`WHERE`**

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    EMS
WHERE
    Utilization >= 0.25
```

**`HAVING`**

```
SELECT
    col1, count(*)
FROM
    EMS
GROUP BY
    col1
HAVING
    count(*) > 10
```

**`HAVING`** and **`WHERE`**

```
SELECT
    col1, count(*)
FROM
    EMS
WHERE
    Utilization >= 0.25
GROUP BY
    col1
HAVING
    count(*) > 10
```

---

**Edit:** This modified query should work for you. I'm not sure why your original query was using a CTE, but I've moved the `case` logic to the CTE.

```
with EMS as
(
    select 
        [ID],
        (
            CASE 
                WHEN Entitlements <= 0 THEN '0'
                ELSE CAST([Activations] as float) / [Entitlements]
            END
        ) as Utilization 
    from
        ReportingView.WTA 
    where
        FiscalMonth = DATENAME(MONTH, @dtDate) + ', ' +  DATENAME(YEAR, @dtDate)
        and ProductGroup = 'AAD'
)
select
    *
from
    EMS
where
    Utilizaiton >= .25
```

Answer (score 1):

The HAVING keyword is only used if you are using a GROUP BY too. What you want is a WHERE but you will not be able to reference Utilization unless you wrap it in a sub select.

Comment: So... like this?

Where  (
   CASE 
    WHEN Entitlements <= 0 THEN '0'
    ELSE CAST([Activations] as float) / [Entitlements]
   END
  ) >= .25
GROUP BY ID, [Activations], [Entitlements]